# Building muscle on low carb diet

Tags: muscle, strength, low-carb

I'm 75kg, 184cm 22 year old healthy male and I do weightlifting to build muscle. I eat around 250g protein, 220g fat and 100g carbohydrates. My body seems to react negatively to a lot of carbs so this is the diet I've chosen.

My goal is purely to gain more muscle mass. Is there any evidence that a low carb diet (substituting with high fat high protein) is detrimental to the muscle-building process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most sources would not classify 100g/day as a low-carb diet, which may affect the relevancy of answers.

But the short answer to your question is **No, not detrimental.**

A book that supports this conclusion and may otherwise be of interest to you: *The Art and Science of Low Carb Performance* by Jeff S. Volek Ph.D., RD and Stephen D. Phinney Ph.D., MD.